# Trying to save a Pyspark Dataframe and I get a Py4JNetworkError - UBUNTU

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on pyspark, that it's installed in an ubuntu machine 16.04, I now need to pull the result, it's quite a long code, the result is a dataframe that I want to save as a csv file, and every time I get the following error, everything works fine but this last line on the code:

```
final_df.write.format('txt').save('final_test1')
```

Could you please advice, what can I do?

```
    ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1035, in send_command
        raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
    py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
        response = connection.send_command(command)
      File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
        "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
    py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 313, in _handle_request_noblock
        self.process_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 341, in process_request
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 235, in handle
    num_updates = read_int(self.rfile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 577, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-f56812202624> in <module>()
      1 final_df.cache()
----> 2 final_df.write.format('csv').save('final_test1')

~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    548             self._jwrite.save()
    549         else:
--> 550             self._jwrite.save(path)
    551 
    552     @since(1.4)

~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    325             raise Py4JError(
    326                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 327                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    328     else:
    329         type = answer[1]

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o3911.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this

```
final_df.write.csv('final_test1.csv')
```

Comment: It works now, with the previous command and also this one. Is it normal that some csv are blank? It always come with hundreds of csv files and some are blank.

Comment: Yes, it's normal as each partition is written individually. But in case you want to output a single file then you can use `coalesce` on your dataframe before writing (but it's not advisable as it'll make your processing sequential). Try `final_df.coalesce(1).write.csv('final_test1.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

The error can also because of the incorrect `jar` file you copied.
Try copying an assembly `jar` file from maven:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11